# Problem on installing Ubuntu 13.04 using VM VirtualBox Manager after clicking RESTART/Windows 8 Intel i7

Tags: installation, 13.04, virtualbox, restart

Here is my problem:

Trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 to use it as VM on Windows 8 Intel i7(not sure if that makes any difference). I use the most recent version of Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.

Downloaded a file from this website: http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/
Clicked on: PC (Intel x86) desktop image
The file name is: ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386

After install it gets to RESTART button and when I click nothing happens.

Just a black screen and all I see a few menu options at the top right Machine, View, Devices, and Help.

Tried installing many times and all of them do not get me anywhere, same issue everytime I reinstall.

Did someone have same issue installing Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Instead of pressing Restart, type ctrl+alt+f1, type sudo umount /dev/sd*, press Enter, wait for the prompt to appear again, then shutdown the virtual machine  (menu Machine >> button "Shutdown the machine"). It's safe to do an unclean shutdown, after you've unmounted the filesystems.

Comment: Can you post your VirtualBox log files?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue with Ubuntu 10.04 on Windows 7. It seems like VirtualBox is not handling the way Ubuntu requests a reset (Windows VMs work fine). I've had to do a hard reset.

[This ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11004) may be related (tracker for Linux VMs crashing on the first reboot after install).